# ¿como puedo enviar un arreglo de una pagina a otra con ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsp

El asunto es así, tengo una consulta SQL que me da una serie de datos en el JSP hago cuentas y agrupaciones que necesito y, en otra pagina, armo un gráfico de lineas por lo que necesito vario datos que tengo en distintos arreglos que necesito para armar el grafico.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo de como pasar un arreglo con ajax y json espero y te sirva.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$array=array();
$array[]=54;
$array[]=32;
$array[]=55;

?>
<a href="#" onclick=" enviar_datos ('respuesta2.php',  '<?php echo json_encode($array);?>')" > enviar arrray </a>
<div id="contenido"></div>

<script>
    function enviar_datos(url,env){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {array: env},
        success: function(data)  {
          $("#contenido").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**respuesta2.php**

```html
<?php 
 $array=json_decode($_POST["array"]);

 echo "Datos devueltos ". $array[0] ." ". $array[1]  ." ".$array[2];
?>
```

Comment: Me sirve @Bart me da una idea de como hacerlo y que investigar para replicarlo en JSP.  Muchas gracias por tu colaboración :D

Comment: Me agrada que te sea útil.